# Maxima won't start, but works in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, maxima

This is very odd, but I've got latest greatest everything -- 26.1; org-mode  9.1.14 9.1.14-9-g131531-elpaplus; maxima-5.42.1 (installed from source) -- and have this in my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path ".../Downloads/maxima-5.42.1/src/")
(setq org-babel-maxima-command ".../Downloads/maxima-5.42.1/src/maxima")
(autoload 'maxima-mode "maxima" "Maxima mode" t)
(autoload 'imaxima "imaxima" "Frontend for maxima with Image support" t)
(autoload 'maxima "maxima" "Maxima interaction" t)
(autoload 'imath-mode "imath" "Imath mode for math formula input" t)
(setq imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ma[cx]" . maxima-mode))
```

And this seems fine for working with the examples in [this](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-maxima.html). However, when I just try to run Maxima by itself (M-x maxima-mode, imaxima, maxima), I get errors:

for maxima or maxima-mode:

```
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, maxima-font-lock
```

for imaxima:

```
 Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, imaxima-autoconf-variables
```

I have imath.el, maxima.el, and imaxima.el from the Maxima distribution in  ~/.emacs.d/maxima with

```
add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/maxima/")
```

early in my .emacs. What am I missing here? Why does org-mode see Maxima and work, while a regular session doesn't?

Comment: I just eliminated the `maxima-font-lock` by putting a copy of `maxima-font-lock.el` in my `.emacs.d/maxima`. Still have the imaxima error.

Comment: I think you added the wrong directory to `load-path`. For an instance in my case the right directory for `load-path` is `/usr/share/maxima/5.41.0/emacs` while the  `maxima` executable resides in `/usr/bin/`. Look for an `emacs` directory in the `maxima` program folder. If you install a program from source you usually also need to run `make` and `make install` on the source.

Comment: I've cleared up these problems, simply by moving all the .el files over to my .emacs.d, not just the three I mentioned. My issues are mainly coming from a) using a latest-greatest version, rather than the available packages (one version old), and b) trying to have a home version install rather than a system install. Everything works now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP found the mistake, and the question and the mistake don't seem to be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

This was a latest-greatest version, while the available package was one version old, and I tried to do a home install rather than a configure/make/make install system install. It all works now -- in org-mode as well as maxima-mode and imaxima. So this is my `.emacs.d/maxima/` contents:

```
imath.el
imaxima-autoconf-variables.el
imaxima.el
imaxima.lisp
maxima.el
maxima-font-lock.el
setup-imaxima-imath.el
```

all from the `maxima-5.42.1/interfaces/emacs/` directory. Here's my init:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/hercynian/.emacs.d/maxima/")
(push "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp" load-path)
(setq org-babel-maxima-command "maxima")
(autoload 'maxima-mode "maxima" "Maxima mode" t)
(autoload 'imaxima "imaxima" "Frontend for maxima with Image support" t)
(autoload 'maxima "maxima" "Maxima interaction" t)
(autoload 'imath-mode "imath" "Imath mode for math formula input" t)
(setq imaxima-use-maxima-mode-flag t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ma[cx]" . maxima-mode))
```

The imaxima docs said to put in the `(push ...)` line. Not sure what it does. It would be nice to have imaxima which turns the "ascii math" output to Latex images work in org-mode.